# How to Trigger a Media Services Reset

Tags: ios, core-audio, avaudiosession

Is there a way to trigger a reset of media services? I would like to test my application's reaction to this, to ensure I'm handling it properly.

Comment: Any chance you figured this out? It would be really useful to me.

Comment: iOS 9 includes a way to reset media services.  I added an answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In iOS 8.4, there is a new option in Developer Settings called Reset Media Services:

[image]

Reference: [Technical Q&A QA1749, Handling AVAudioSessionMediaServicesWereResetNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/qa/qa1749/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011192)

Comment: This is available in iOS 8.4 as well

Comment: This is available in iOS 8.2 as well, not sure about previous versions.